# jQuery: Recursive page break based on div overflow

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, overflow

I would like to know if it is possible to run a recursive function which places html from a source into a `div`, and once the `div` reaches overflow, creates a new `div`. Repeating the process until complete.

Essentially, I am trying to create a document viewer from parsed xml, however, finding the the right place to insert a "separator" or page break seems a little more difficult than first anticipated. Any word of advice are very much appreciated.

Additionally, if anybody knows a jQuery plugin which handles XML and parses it into a "document" viewer, than feel free to comment. Thanks again. :3

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

http://jparse.kylerush.net/